# SSH tunnel to browse localhost, super slow

Tags: server, ssh

To visit sites/services like jupyter notebooks and rstudio-server on my server I make a ssh tunnel and then just browse them in my webbrowser on my local machine, however, since yesterday, all my services are loading so slow in my browser.
Not sure why or where to even start the troubleshooting. I can ssh into the server and look at file etc. I even tried reinstall one of the services yesterday before I realized that all of my services were slow...
Any ideas or recommendations how to troubleshoot this?

Edit: can add that if I manage to connect to one service in the browser, it seems that once i'm connected the service runs without delays in the browsers. So seems that it's "just" the connecting that takes forever. (several mins)
Can also add that the ports are open on both my remote and local machine.

I just now realized that in my terminal I get the following message:

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

The command I used to open up the tunnel:

```
ssh -N -f -L 8787:localhost:8787 myNick@192.168.1.xx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seem to be with the DNS on the target server, changing from localhost to 127.0.0.1 works but do not really solve the DNS problem on the target machine.